# Can't collapse pieces of code after doing Ctrl + M, P

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

`Ctrl + M, P` expands the whole document. But after doing this I can't collapse back specific methods or pieces of code. It's not possible via shortcut keys (for example: `Ctrl + M, M`) neither via the menu:

As you can see, only `Ctrl + M, O` is possible which collapses the whole document

[image: Only <code>Ctrl + M, O</code> is possible]

Also the `+` en `-` signs disappear when I do `Ctrl + M, P`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS2012 toggling outline expansion is [CTRL] + M, M.  I presume this hasn't changed from previous version. Don't have VS2010 to check...

Comment: The problem occurs when doing Ctrl + M, P

Comment: That is because [CTRL] + M, P is bound to "stop outlining", which is what you describe is happening.

Comment: @Ozkan to fix the problem you will need to go to the edit menu/outlining/Start Automatic Outlining - which by default is not bound to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: There is no menu item like 'Start Automatic Outlining'

Comment: I see, When I do Ctrl + M, P (to expand all code) then VS stops outlining automatically which is very strange... Then I have to enable outlining again... very strange..

Comment: No, I think you've got it wrong - [CTRL] + M, P is not expanding all code, it is stopping outlining, which appears to expand all code. A better choice is probably [CTRL] + M, L, which toggles all outlining.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, and some of this is in the comments, but I'll tie it all together in an official answer since I recently did the same thing accidentally in Visual Studio 2015 and it took me a while to figure out what I had done.

The CTRL+M, CTRL+P combination turns off outlining for the current document. It is possible to turn it back on by closing and re-opening the document as long as the "Enter outlining mode when files open" option is checked under Tools|Options|Text Editor|C#|Advanced. (there are similar options for other editor types - you can search on "outline" in the options dialog to see them all).

If you find yourself doing this often, there is a command to turn outlining back on, however, it is not assigned a keyboard shortcut by default. You can assign one though.

1. Open the Tools|Options|Environment|Keyboard dialog.
2. Enter "outli" under "Show commands containing" and look through the list below for the one named "Edit.StartAutomaticOutlining".
3. When you click on it, it will either show you what keys are currently assigned if a shortcut is already assigned, or will indicate nothing is assigned.
4. If there isn't anything listed, select "Editor" from "Use new shortcut in", then in the "Press shortcut keys" box, press the key combination you want to assign it to. For example, I used CTRL+M, CTRL+[.

Now if you accidentally hit CTRL-M, CTRL-P and turn off outlining, you can quickly re-enable outlining with CTRL-M, CTRL-[.